# does Mathf.PerlinNoise() rely on the internal random number generator?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random, perlin-noise

I am using Unity c#, and I am coding something that relies on Perlin noise to determine a random number between 0 and 1. I would like to implement a feature in my code that allows the user to define a specific pre-determined seed number to use for this, but I am not sure if the Perlin noise function actually uses the same random seed as the Random class does.

For example; if I want to generate Perlin noise using Mathf.PerlinNoise() - will it always be the same if I always set the RNG seed priory, using the same number?

minimal code example:

```
Random.InitState(4815162342);
    float _randomSample = Mathf.PerlinNoise(yada yada yada);
```

I would like to use this for a Minecraft-like system of generating a procedural game world and having a way for the player to choose a seed would be great. in that code example, the player's chosen seed was the numbers from the TV show "Lost". (4815162342)

Comment: *will it always be the same if I always set the RNG seed priory, using the same number?* - what happened when you tried doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two are **not** related!

The only thing that [`Random.InitState`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.InitState.html) changes is the way how e.g. `Random.Range` or `Random.value` work.

Without using it it would simply use values based on the system time instead.

---

`Mathf.PerlinNoise` is not connected to that. You can actually try different seeds and always see the same perlin result. This is actually stated in the [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PerlinNoise.html)

> The same coordinates will always return the same sample value but the plane is essentially infinite so it is easy to avoid repetition by choosing a random area to sample from.

They already give you a hint how to solve your problem: Use a different offset!

Now here comes your seed into play: Simply choose a random offset based on the seed -> random but always equal for the same seed!

```
Random.InitState(4815162342);
var randomOffsetX = Random.value;
var rabdomOffsetY = Random.value;

var values = new float[25];
for(var x = 0; x < 5; x++)
{
    for(var y = 0; y < 5; y++) 
    {
        values[x*5 + y] = Mathf.PerlinNoise(x + randomOffsetX, y + randomOffsetY);
    }
}
```

This should give you 25 random values (between 0 and 1). But they should be equal for every time you use the same seed.

---

If you actually don't need the noise pattern but only one single value basically you could achieve the same thing simply using

```
Random.InitState(4815162342);
var value = Random.Range(0f, 1f);
```